# Webforms DetailsView not saving data on edit/update

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, binding, webforms, detailsview

The user comes to this page to edit/update details for particular Employee. The employee details are shown in a DetailsView, which is bound to Northwind database. The problem is when I click Edit and change some data and then click Update - the fields returns to the initial state as if nothing has changed.

Webform code:

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsViewEditEmployee" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateRows="False"         
        Height="50px" 
        Width="314px"            
        OnItemCommand="DetailsViewEditEmployee_ItemCommand"
        OnModeChanging="DetailsViewEditEmployee_ModeChanging"
        OnItemUpdating="DetailsViewEditEmployee_ItemUpdating"
        OnItemUpdated="DetailsViewEditEmployee_ItemUpdated" >
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="EmployeeID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="False" SortExpression="EmployeeID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />               
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" CausesValidation="False" ShowEditButton="True" />           
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
    CustomerID:
   <asp:Literal Text="text" runat="server" id="LiteralCustomerId" Mode="Encode" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Employees] WHERE [EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [Title], [Address], [City]) VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName, @Title, @Address, @City)" SelectCommand="SELECT [EmployeeID], [LastName], [FirstName], [Title], [Address], [City] FROM [Employees]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Employees] SET [LastName] = @LastName, [FirstName] = @FirstName, [Title] = @Title, [Address] = @Address, [City] = @City WHERE [EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="EmployeeID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>        
</form>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class EmployeesEdit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Params["Id"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("EmployeesRepeater.aspx");
        }

        this.LiteralCustomerId.Text = Request.Params["id"];
        var id = int.Parse(Request.Params["id"]);
        using (var context = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            var employees = context.Employees;
            var empToList = employees.ToList();
            var current =
                from emp in empToList
                where emp.EmployeeID == id
                select emp;
            this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.DataSource = current;
            this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void DetailsViewEditEmployee_ModeChanging(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
        {
            this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);
            this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.DataBind(); // add this and check
        }
        if (e.CancelingEdit)
        {
            this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);
            this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.DataBind(); // add this and check
        }
    }

    protected void DetailsViewEditEmployee_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewValues.Count; i++)
        {
            if (e.NewValues[i] != null)
            {
                e.NewValues[i] = Server.HtmlEncode(e.NewValues[i].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    protected void DetailsViewEditEmployee_ItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.DataBind();          
    }

    protected void DetailsViewEditEmployee_ItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("New"))
        {
            this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
            this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.DataBind();
        }
        else if (e.CommandName.Equals("Edit"))
        {
            this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
            this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.DataBind();
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should databid the `DetailsView` only on the initial load, not on every postback:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    using (var context = new NorthwindEntities())
    {
        var employees = context.Employees;
        var empToList = employees.ToList();
        var current =
            from emp in empToList
            where emp.EmployeeID == id
            select emp;
        this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.DataSource = current;
        this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.DataBind();
    }
}
```

`Page_Load` is triggered before events, by databinding it again you prevent events from being fired.

Comment: Ok, but when I did what you suggested on clicking Edit button the DetailsView just disappears from the page.

Comment: @Todo: I don't know why it disappears, do you make it invisible somewhere? You should extract a method `DataBindDetailsViewEditEmployee` where you move all code from `Page_Load` that is inside (including) the `using`-statement. Then you can call this method from `Page_Load`(`!IsPostBack`) and also from the events where you need to rebind the `DetailsView`.  Then you just have to replace this line `this.DetailsViewEditEmployee.DataBind();` with `DataBindDetailsViewEditEmployee();`.